# iPhone browser not showing CSS sprite

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Could anyone tell me why desktop browsers (Chrome, Safari, Firefox) are showing a CSS background sprite image and the iPhone browser is not?

I have the issue with the social sharing buttons. The first 4 sharing buttons come from the WordPress theme, and the email button was added by me.

The email button is shown on desktop, but not on mobile and I'm not getting why?

I appreciate your help.

Was a problem with selecting classes correctly. Selecting the parent and than the child solved the problem

```
.parentclass .child {background-size:...;}
```

Comment: One very tall blank page in iOS 7.1.1/Safari, with exactly the same on Windows 7/Chrome, Windows7/Firefox 30, Windows 7/IE 10.

Comment: @setek There's a `visibility: hidden` at the `body` level, untick it and it should show.

Comment: sorry was updating w3 total cache and had a wrong include order. page should be available now

Comment: @FuzzBall007 can you do that on iOS/Safari? Really? I didn't know ..

Comment: @setek Yes, it's called [Remote Debugging](http://moduscreate.com/enable-remote-web-inspector-in-ios-6/)

Comment: didn't new about ios remote debugging! awesome! unlucky I don't have an iPhone do you now how to use this with the ios simulator in xcode?

Comment: @FuzzBall007, remote debugging also works with android https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging however I couldn't find the problem.

Comment: Thx for reposting the question at: http://tweakswp.com/iphone-browser-not-showing-css-sprite/ and http://wordpressrelated.com/iphone-not-showing-css-sprite/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.td-sp-share-email` is being called for your special email and WhatsApp icons:

ln33:

```
.td-sp-share-email {
    width: 31px;
    height: 31px;
    background: url("/wp-content/uploads/social-sprites.png") 0px 0px !important;
}
```

However, you have a rule in `style.css?b9d887` that is still setting the `background-size` property, to `91px 2230px !important`:

ln10516:

```
.td-sp {
    background-size: 91px 2230px !important;
}
```

Your image, `social-sprites.png`, is only `38px` by `76px`. Your `background-size` is the problem.

Update your `background-size` to what's appropriate and it will work.

Comment: added that. doesn't fix the problem on mobie devices though :(

Comment: What did you set background size to? And did you use !important also, to override the first !important?

Comment: to the sprite size: background-size: 38px 76px !important;

Comment: And have you checked if it's still being overridden by the style.css rule? Are your rules exactly the same specificity?

Comment: its somehow random. on desktop ln33 overwrites style.css however on mobile devices it is the other way round and I'm not understanding why.

Comment: It made a difference with which class I selected the element. Selecting it with the upper class of the parent anyhow solved the problem